# Intersection of data in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, combinations, slice, intersection

I have two columns in a table.One represents work and the other represents date on which that needs to perform..I need the output as a minimum possible combination. For the below records I am expecting the output as W1,W2,W3 on 16th and 17th . And W4,W5 on 20th. Is there anyway to achieve this in a query?

```
W1  15-06-2015
W1  16-06-2015
W1  17-06-2015
W2  16-06-2015
W2  17-06-2015
W2  18-06-2015
W3  16-06-2015
W3  17-06-2015
W4  20-06-2015
W4  21-06-2015
W5  20-06-2015
```

Comment: What do you mean, "minimum possible combination".  Not clear.

Comment: What is the logic that you want to implement?  Do you want to return any rows where there exists another row with the same date and a different Wx value?  "minimum possible combination" may make a great deal of sense to you but I'm afraid it's not particularly clear to me.

Comment: If I take 16th and 17th i can cover W1 W2 and W3..since W1 W2 W3 have intersection on 16th and 17th..

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to clarify anything for me.  Do you want to return any rows where there exists another row with the same date and a different Wx value?

Comment: @MariaGeorge my solution solves the question, if it didn't answer your question that's fine. But if it helped provide you with the solution then accepting it would be a common courtesy. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
select Date, wm_concat(work) work_concat from table group by Date
```

Then you can order by length(work_concat) if that gives you the output you're looking for.  From what I can gather, you want the maximum intersection of work, correct?

However, if you want to just be given the maximum intersection and no other records, this will do that:

```
    select to_char(work_concat), dateFieldb from (

select rank() over (partition by work order by length(work_concat) desc) rn, c.* from (
select dateFieldb, work_Concat, a.work from work a
inner join (
select DateField dateFieldb, wm_concat(work) work_concat from work a group by DateField
  ) b on b.work_concat like ('%' || a.work || '%')
  ) c

) where rn = 1
group by to_char(work_concat), dateFieldb


TO_CHAR(WORK_CONCAT)  DATEFIELDB
--------------------------------
W1,W3,W2              16-JUN-15  
W1,W3,W2              17-JUN-15  
W4,W5                 20-JUN-15
```

Comment: Yes..Concat is fine but I cannot use length for removing unwanted dates...Same length may be possible with other combinations too..

Comment: Either way the second query I posted above does exactly what you want.  Assuming you want your output to look as above.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g use function `listagg()` twice:

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7a9af/1)</sup>

```
select listagg(wdate, ', ') within group (order by works) dates, works
  from (
    select wdate, listagg(wid, ', ') within group (order by wid) works
      from data group by wdate)
  group by works;
```

... or if you are interested only in combinations containing more than one common value:

```
select dates, works from (
    select listagg(wdate, ', ') within group (order by works) dates, works, 
        cnt1, count(1) cnt2
      from (
        select wdate, listagg(wid, ', ') within group (order by wid) works,
            count(1) cnt1
          from data group by wdate)
      group by works, cnt1)
  where cnt1 >1 or cnt2>1
```

Comment: This is a cool solution but it does not output the correct results as per OP.

Comment: @PhilipDevine - thank you for comment. This is how I understood words: _I need the output as a minimum possible combination_ etc.
If needed output is such as you think - solution with listagg() is [much simpler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7a9af/3).